# Add Role attribute to MVC3 methods only in Release mode?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes, active-directory, authorization

Is it possible to add an `[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]` (as an example) to an MVC3 Controller Method but ONLY in Release mode?

The Test environment I have access to at the moment has no AD, but Live does - so I'd like to add the attribute only in release mode.

**EDIT: Problem when using #if**

```
using...
using...
using MyWebsite.Helpers;

namespace MyWebsite.Controllers.Admin
{
#if !DEBUG
    [RedirectAuthorize(Roles = "Admin")]
#endif
    [DatabaseDependant]
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
      ...
    }
```

As soon as I add the `#if` then I get an error on `using MyWebsite.Helpers;` saying this cannot be found (and my custom attribute [DatabaseDependant] is not found as a result)

If I recompile, then it works...temporarily...until I pretty much edit anything...whereupon I have to re-compile again.

Am I missing a trick here?  Why is adding the `#if` making this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could surround it with:

```
#if !DEBUG
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
#endif
```