# MVC3 Redirect to "Unauthorized" page not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

After asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8879455/449156) about authorization, I've added a new custom attribute in an attempt to redirect unauthorised users to a page which has more details on requesting access etc etc.

```
public class RedirectAuthorize:AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            //base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("Unauthorized");
        }
    }
```

I've decorated my Home controller with this attribute and the correct (Role="...") and this "works"..i.e. it hits the method as and when expected.

I've added a vanilla view to the Shared views folder called `Unauthorized.cshtml` but I just get "The resource cannot be found" 404 error.

The URL displayed appears to be correct?

My guess is I need to specify a controller/action instead of a page? but the Error handler redirects to `Error.cshtml` without needing a controller?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is you are using `RedirectResult` which forces the browser to request the given URL. But when the browser requests it there is no route that matches. Hence it throws a 404 error.

Try

```
filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Unauthorized" };
```

Comment: So simple, so obvious. (So why didn't I think of that!)